# npm typescript override index.d.ts "/// <reference types="

Tags: typescript, npm

After calling `npm install` I have one `index.d.ts` in which the `/// <reference types="[WrongPath]"/>` is wrong.

I am new to npm and typescript (and generally web development); Is it possible to override the generated index.d.ts file and set the `reference types` to something else?

So if `npm install` is called the correct reference is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a job that will automatically run after npm install to replace that one line.